# Chrome extension doesnt want to install inline

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i wrote a little extension to my site.

I've added my site in [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/#?modal_active=none) in purpose of verified, which is [www.love2live.pl](http://www.love2live.pl).

I've a button on my site Add to chrome, when i click in, then i got a message like:
**inline install failed: Installs can only be initiated by one of the Chrome Web Store item's verified sites.**

My extension is a private, but people with link may find it, i dont't know what i should to do yet, that will be working fine.

In `<head>` i added:

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/myID" >
```

and in button i added:

```
<button onclick="chrome.webstore.install(undefined, undefined, function(err) {console.log('inline install failed: ' + err)})" id="install-button">Add to Chrome</button>
```

Any solutions?

Regards,
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/7YUFuHvj9P0). There might be an issue with https verified sites. Try to switch the verified domain to not be SSL and see if it works. Also according to this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation), inline installations can only be initiated by a page on a site that is [verified](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34592) (via [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/)) as being associated with that item in the Chrome Web Store for security reasons. You may double check your configuration.